# Java iterate through JList which contains JPanel - JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I am trying to iterate over a JList where each item contains:
JPanel - JLabel

Currently what i have is:

```
System.out.println("Reading all list items:");
System.out.println("-----------------------");
for (int i = 0; i < menuList.getModel().getSize(); i++) {
     Object item = menuList.getModel().getElementAt(i);;
     System.out.println("Item = " + item);
}
```

The output i get is:

> Item =
>   javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]

Instead i want to access the text that is inside the JPanel.

How could this be done?

Edit:
This is how i add my JPanel to the JList

```
        menuList = new JList(v);
        v = new Vector <String> ();
        menuList.setListData(v);
.....

    // get our images
    Icon pingImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/icnNew.png"));

    // add the images to jlabels with text
    JLabel pingLabel = new JLabel("Hi there", pingImage, JLabel.LEFT);

    // create the corresponding panels
    JPanel pingPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    // add the labels onto the panels
    pingPanel.add(pingLabel);

    v.add(pingPanel);
```

So the text i want to find is "Hi there"

Comment: what text is inside the panel?? what property?

Comment: @JBNizet, request you to use polite and professional language.

Comment: Well i am sorry, i am new to Java still. However it has to be possible to somehow access what is stored in the JLabel that is stored within the JPanel

Comment: read Oracle tutorial How to use List and How to use Tables for Renderers concept (same/veri similair for JTable, JList, JComboBox)

Comment: `Edit: This is how i add my JPanel to the JList` - the same comment as my above, and (without any changes comment) as by @JBNizet,

Comment: @SidCool: would you mind explaining me what is impolite and unprofessional in my comment, please?

Answer (score 0):

Then what you need is to check for the elements inside that JPanel. I mean, a panel is a container of UI elements, that said, you need to check for the elements, once you checked for that you need to compare whether it is a label or not, if it is a label then you will be able to get the text of that label.

Can't you show us the code, probably could be easier if you provide the snippet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm sleepless hahaha. Checking (: EDIT: Ok, I see, and it is just what I've stated before. This link may help you to understand the way you're grouping the components http://java.ittoolbox.com/documents/how-to-find-components-inside-a-jpanel-container-18187 so you could iterate over the components and do whatever you want with them. Hope it helps (: